# How to fix this MVC website error: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I have MVC3 installed on my dedicated server and I have an mvc3 website running there, the problem is:
In some pages I get this error:
"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0"

[image]

And I don't know what is the problem because it didn't happen before in this website or any MVC3 website on the same server.

Note: The issue is happening in some pages I am using grid helper in, but there are some other pages has grid helper and working fine.

I tried this as well: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx  while i know it is an old post, but with no hope as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must have installed or updated some NuGet package in your project that depends on Razor WebPages v2 (`System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0`) which is part of the upcoming ASP.NET MVC 4 release.

Take a look at all the referenced assemblies and inspect their dependencies.

Comment: so this can be solved if i installed mvc4 on the server, or may make conflicts?

Comment: No, if you have only installed ASP.NET MVC 4 on the server there won't be any problems. Issues will occur if you reference some assembly from it in your web application.

Comment: after installing mvc4, my server will have mvc3 and 4 installed in the same time, is that ok?

Comment: Yes, it should be OK. Installing ASP.NET MVC 4 shouldn't break existing ASP.NET MVC 3 applications unless you modify somehow those applications to use components of ASP.NET MVC 4 in which case you might get conflicts. Actually in your case it seems that your application somehow depends on an ASP.NET MVC 4 assembly which is not installed.